# Webmin /var/www Folder delete, while deleting user

Tags: linux, directory, var, webmin

Webmin File manager /var/www/ directory delete, how I can recover that folder from webmin.

Comment: Restore it from a backup. (Filesystem Backup and/or Bacula Backup System module) If you don't have backups, now would be a better-late-than-never time to configure some.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the files are deleted, they cannot be recovered in `Linux` as far as I know. Also To my knowledge, `webmin` does not have special storage for deleted files.

What I suggest is that you should do 'updatedb' and search for the files if you did a backup somewhere which you might have forgotten about it(no harm trying luck right?).